# If $2^r b^2$ is an even almost perfect number that is NOT a power of two, does it follow that $r=1$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, solution-verification, divisor-sum, arithmetic-functions

(The following are taken from this [preprint by Antalan and Dris](https://arxiv.org/abs/1602.04248).)

Antalan and Tagle showed that an even [almost perfect number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_perfect_number) $n \neq 2^t$ must necessarily have the form $2^r b^2$ where $r \geq 1$, $\gcd(2,b)=1$, and $b$ is an odd composite.

---

**FIRST CLAIM:** $2^r b^2$ is not a square.

**PROOF OF FIRST CLAIM:** This trivially follows from $\gcd(2,b)=1$ and the fact that $b$ is composite.

> Edit: (October 19, 2022 - 5:17 PM Manila time) - This proof for Claim #1 is flawed, please see the rebuttal by [Jaap Scherphuis](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/362967) in the [comments](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4554888/if-2r-b2-is-an-even-almost-perfect-number-that-is-not-a-power-of-two-does-i?noredirect=1#comment9583931_4554888).

---

**SECOND CLAIM:** $2^r b^2$ is not squarefree.

**PROOF OF SECOND CLAIM:** This also trivially follows from $\gcd(2,b)=1$ and the fact that $b$ is composite.

---

**THIRD CLAIM:** $2^r b^2$ has a *unique* representation as the product of its *squarefree part* and *square part*.

**PROOF OF THIRD CLAIM:** This follows from the fact that $2^r b^2$ is neither a square nor squarefree.

---

> Since $\gcd(2,b)=1$, then the square part of $2^r b^2$ is $b^2$, and the squarefree part of $2^r b^2$ is $2^r$.  This would imply that $r \leq 1$.  But we know that $r \geq 1$.

> Therefore, it follows that $r = 1$.

> Furthermore, we then know that $r = 1$ holds if and only if $2^r b^2 \equiv 2 \pmod 3$.

---

Here is our question:

> Is our proof for $r = 1$ logically correct?  If not, how can it be mended so as to produce a valid argument?

Comment: Is there an analogue condition for possible positive integers $n$ with $\sigma(n)=2n+1$ ? As far as I know, no such number is known.

Comment: @Peter: Off-hand, I do not know of an analogue condition for possible positive integers with $\sigma(n) = 2n + 1$.  As to their existence, I also think that it is currently an open problem.

Comment: @Peter: Found it!  [This MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/270240) (and the corresponding answer) proves that, if $\sigma(n) = 2n + 1$, then $n$ is an odd (perfect) square.  ("Perfect" in the sense of being a "perfect power", and **not** in the sense of being a "perfect number".)

Comment: $2^rb^2$ will be square whenever $r$ is even, but your proof for claim 1 says nothing about $r$ at all.

Comment: Also, doesn't every number have a unique representation as a product of a square and a square-free part, just by unique factorization?

Comment: @JaapScherphuis: I was thinking along the lines of "Since $\gcd(2,b)=1$, then $2^r \neq b^2$, which means that $2^r b^2$ cannot be a square".  Looking at your rebuttal, I can see that my original argument for Claim 1 is flawed.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis: Yes indeed, every number has a unique representation as a product of a square part and a squarefree part, although I am unfamiliar with a proof of this statement that uses unique factorization.

Comment: In that case, I don't understand what you are proving in claim 3. Or were you trying to say that $2^r$ is necessarily the square-free part? That isn't true. If the number is not square then $r$ is odd, and the square-free part is $2$ because $2^r$ is divisible by the square $2^{r-1}$.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis: Indeed, your point in your [last comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4554888/if-2r-b2-is-an-even-almost-perfect-number-that-is-not-a-power-of-two-does-i?noredirect=1#comment9583965_4554888) is the entire crux of my [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4556398/28816) below.  (That is, my original proof argument for $r=1$ cannot be right since it would produce an *equally dubious* proof for $k=1$, where $q^k n^2$ is an odd perfect number with special prime $q$.)

Answer (score 0):

This is not a direct answer to the original question, just some remarks that would be too long to fit in the comments.

---

Blimey!  The argument so presented for $r=1$ *"cannot be correct"*.  Here is why:

> Consider the related problem of determining whether $k=1$ holds, where $q^k n^2$ is an [odd perfect number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_number#Odd_perfect_numbers) with special prime $q$ satisfying $q \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $\gcd(q,n)=1$.

> (Note that $q^k \neq n^2$ since $\gcd(q,n)=1$.  This means that, since $q \geq 5$ and $k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$, then $q^k n^2$ is not a square.  Evidently, $q^k n^2$ is not squarefree.)

> Since $\gcd(q,n)=\gcd(q^k,n^2)=1$, then the square part of $q^k n^2$ is $n^2$, and the squarefree part of $q^k n^2$ is $q^k$.  This would imply that $k \leq 1$.  But we know that $k \geq 1$, since $k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ holds.

> Therefore, it follows that $k=1$.

Comment: The following [MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4437365) (and the answer contained therein) is then relevant.